# How to tell pgfplots to use math font for manually selected tick labels

Tags: pgfplots, fonts, math-fonts

I have a `pgfplots` axis, displaying some data. The ticklabels are defined manually, so the standard font used is the base text font.

What I would like to do is to obtain tick labels using the math font of my document without putting all of my ticklabels in math mode using `$ ... $`.

Basically, I think I just need to add some `ticklabel style={font=\mathseries}` but I don't know what command to use instead of `\mathseries`.

I apologize in advance for this somewhat dummy question.

**CLOSE EDIT**

> I used [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/281512/141947) in the duplicate link, not the accepted answer.

**Edit**: I  updated the MWE, removing `mtpro2`, which actually changes the output, but not the issue.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{times}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=5cm,
height=5cm,
at={(0cm,0cm)},
scale only axis,
plot box ratio=1 1 1,
xmin=0,
xmax=10,
xtick={0,2,4,6},
% HERE THE LABELS DEPEND ON THE MATH MODE
xticklabels={$0.12$,0.12,$0.345$,0.345},
ymin=-0.5,ymax=9.5,
ytick=\empty,
zmin=0.0000e+00,
zmax=10,
view={-4.4000e+01}{5.9600e+01},
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left,
axis z line*=left,
ticklabel style={font={\footnotesize}},
]

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Result without `mtpro2`
[image]

Result with `mtpro2`
[image]

As you can see, the labels within `$ ... $` and the other labels have different fonts.

**Edit 2** Comment regarding the use of `assume math mode` from pgfmanual v3.0.1a p954

> /pgf/number format/assume math mode={hbooleani} (default true)
>   Set this to true if you don’t want any checks for math mode. The initial setting checks whether math
>   mode is active using \pgfutilensuremath for each final number.
>   Use assume math mode=true if you know that math mode is active. In that case, the final number is
>   typeset as-is, no further checking is performed.

**Edit 3** I added a `xticklabel={$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}$}` after the `xticklabels={...}` call. I actually overwrites the manually defined `xticklabels` and uses the values in `xtick` but gives the desired math output...

**Updated MWE**

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{times}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{xticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber[assume math mode=true]{\tick}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=5cm,
height=5cm,
at={(0cm,0cm)},
scale only axis,
plot box ratio=1 1 1,
xmin=0,
xmax=10,
xtick={0,2,4,6},
% HERE THE LABELS DEPEND ON THE MATH MODE
xticklabels={$0.12$,0.12,$0.345$,0.345},
%PRINTS THE TICKS IN MATH MODE BUT NOT THE MANUALLY SET TICKLABELS
xticklabel={$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}$},
ymin=-0.5,ymax=9.5,
ytick=\empty,
zmin=0.0000e+00,
zmax=10,
view={-4.4000e+01}{5.9600e+01},
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left,
axis z line*=left,
ticklabel style={font={\footnotesize}},
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: they are already in math mode. So if you don't do anything they should pickup the math font.

Comment: If I compile the document, I don't get the same result for xticklabels and yticklabels

Comment: mtpro is not longer on ctan.  The replacement, mtp2lite, isn't either, at least not directly.

Comment: Yes, it is not available on CTAN. mtp2lite is freely available, but I will try to reproduce the error without it.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, I removed `mtpro2`, but the problem remains.

Comment: @percusse The MWE demonstrates that it is not the case here, maybe because of the package `times`?

Comment: @anderstood I still can't see the obvious. What is the difference in this output? inline math characters are different and they are picked up as math font.

Comment: @percusse If you compare the fives (or the twos) in the bottom right of the picture, they obviously have different fonts. I think the OP would like to type labels such as `{0.12, 3.45, ...}` so that they are rendered as they had typed `{$0.12$, $3.45$, ...}`.

Comment: @anderstood, that's exactly what I need ;)

Comment: I don't know why `\pgfplotsset{xticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber[assume math mode=false]{\tick}}}` does not work (see  [373722](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/373722/how-can-i-leave-math-mode-in-pgf-plots-ticks)).

Comment: @anderstood Doing  `assume math mode=true` only seems to leave the result as it is no matter what the value contains. See the edit in the question. However, there is no explanation on what `assume math mode=false` should do. Only check for math environment ? enforce math environment ?

Comment: If you add a math font, it seems to work fine. For example try `\usepackage{mathptmx}`. See also [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9686/34258). If you're using `mtpro2` I don't know what the problem is, but the difference might be unnoticeable...

Comment: @anderstood, I just edited the post to show the result with `mtpro2`

Comment: This question is similar: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/281503/159527 and its accepted answer should do what you want. The third method looks especially suitable.

Comment: @RobotRaven, thanks ! It took me a long time searching for an answer before asking this one, but I guess it is relying a lot on how the question is aked. Actually, the accepted answer does not seem to work for me, and egreg's answer feels like the right one to me.